# how use explode for dict in php

Tags: php, dictionary, key-value, explode

how use explode for this kind of dict
I have  try this code but get error
that something wrong
`one = explode("placeholder="WithdrawAmount" value="", $py); $two = explode(">", $one[1]);`

so anyone know how to use it please    i want to print the value of this placeholder
it give me this error

[image]

Comment: Could you please include the error you’re seeing?

Comment: i add screen for it

Answer (score 0):

Check this string:
`"placeholder="WithdrawAmount" value=""`

The double quotes are not escaped and the string is not closed.

The following ones should work better:
`'placeholder="WithdrawAmount" value=""'` or `"placeholder=\"WithdrawAmount\" value=\"\""`

Comment: is it allowed to use single ' and " in php ?

Comment: not working man 

Comment: You can use single and double quotes in php, as other delimiters. All have significant differences. I strongly suggest you to read the [string docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for further info. Briefly, one of the main differences is that single quotes does not expand all special characters (in my example double quotes inside single ones are not escaped, while they are insinde double quotes). This may be useful with HTML, for example. Another difference is that PHP parser will not look for variables to expand inside single quotes, resulting somewhat faster.

Comment: Please, (take the habit to) elaborate more what is not working. Do you receive an error? If so, add it to your comment. Does it not behave as you expect? Describe the behaviour you obtain, if possible with some example data.